# how can I merge two sets of text files with same suffix as file name?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two sets of files, the first set of files are:

```
apple_sweet_1.txt
apple_sweet_2.txt
apple_sweet_3.txt
```

Now, the second set of files I have are:

```
mango_sweet_1.txt
mango_sweet_2.txt
mango_sweet_3.txt
```

I want to cat the respective files in a bash loop so I could get something like this (of course, I don't want to do this individually):

```
cat apple_sweet_1.txt mango_sweet_1.txt > sweet_1.txt
cat apple_sweet_2.txt mango_sweet_2.txt > sweet_2.txt
cat apple_sweet_3.txt mango_sweet_3.txt > sweet_3.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `for` loop:

```
for i in apple_sweet_*.txt; do
   p="${i#apple_}"
   [[ -f "mango_$p" ]] && cat "$i" "mango_$p" > "$p"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

**`bash`** solution:

```
for f in apple_sweet_*.txt; do 
    if [[ "$f" =~ .*_([0-9]+).txt ]]; then 
        idx=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}              # getting file numeric index
        mango_fn="mango_sweet_${idx}.txt"   # related `mango` filename
        [ -f "$mango_fn" ] && cat "$f" "$mango_fn" > "sweet_${idx}.txt"
    fi
done
```